# Including generated fields to Django JSON serialization

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have a django app where i have an api defined as follows:

Here is what is what i am sending in my json from my `api.py`:

```
class studentList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        student_detail = Student.objects.filter(student_id = pk)
        serialized_student_detail = studentSerializer(student_detail, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_student_detail.data)
```

I have another variable named **status** which i am calculating with the help of reverse lookups.
What i am trying to achieve is to send another field named status along with the above json values. Since my model does not have a **status** field in it, How do i achieve this?

Comment: And the API app you use is? (RestFramework or Tastypie)

Comment: i am using Django rest framework

Comment: So you basically want to send a json that looks like { 'status': x, 'student_detail_list': [ ... ] } ?

Comment: i have a status that i am calculating for every item in the student-detail_list. so i want like [ { 'status': x1, 'student_detail1' : y1},{ 'status': x2, 'student_detail2' : y2}... ]

Answer (score 1):

What you may need is a SerializerMethodField (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).
Note that by default it is a read only field.